# Set Margins Between Linear Layout Programatically

Tags: android, android-layout

I am dynamically adding linearlayouts to a main linearlayout which is contained in a scrollview.
Scrollview --> MainLinearLayout --> Childrens.

Now i wanted some space between childrens so i i did the following :

```
 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,height_layout);
            lp.setMargins(50,50,50,50);
            linearLayout.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

But i am unable to see any space between the childrens they all are stuck with each other.

Height width works fine but not the margins.

Comment: What is the Problem ? your `Layout` is `Relative` or `Linear` ?

Comment: @jaydroider My layout is linear .

Comment: What this contains `linearLayout` in which you are setting params ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` if you want to set things to `LinearLayout`

e.g.:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,height_layout);
lp.setMargins(50,50,50,50);
linearLayout.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Comment: This will crash the app.
LinearLayout is the children of relativelayout . read this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15501831/add-layout-with-parameters-programmatically-android)

Comment: @Techie however, in your case, your LinearLayout is a child of LinearLayout, isn't it?

Comment: Yes i will try it out and let you know earlier it use to crash

Answer (score 0):

**Use below code**

```
((RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)linearLayout.getLayoutParams()).setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
```